# How do I add disabled class an anchor link if textbox is empty in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

My code is below:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.name" required/>    
<a href="#" ng-class="{disabled: 'bla bla'}">Next Page</a>
```

What should I write instead of `bla bla`? By the way, this is not a form.

Comment: `{disabled: user.name}` or `{disabled: user.name == undefined}` or `{disabled: user.name == ''}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11203/

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" required/>

<a href="#" ng-class="{disabled:user.name== undefined}">Next Page</a>
```

This will add the class disabled if the value inside input is undefined

Answer (score 0):

It works properly for me.

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="inputExperience" ng-model="postContent" placeholder="Post here..."></textarea></br>

<a href ng-click="addPost(site._id)" ng-class="{disabled:postContent== undefined || postContent.length==0}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"><b>Thread & Issue Post......</b></a></br>
```